# Is there any way to help Celina?

Tags: the-witcher

In chapter 4:

Is there any way to help Celina? I went to her with the wreath of immortalles, and she said to crown her. Then the wreath disappeared from inventory, and nothing else happened.

When I go to Julien to tell him about Alina, I say something like "etc. etc. Alina passed on, Celina... there was no way to help her".

I don't get why... Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem... You found any solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Seems there is nothing you can do about this (regarding the dialog anyway). Regarding the nothing happened when I gave her the wreath, I loaded the game and gave it again and she thanked me then disappeared (probably was a glitch the first time I gave it to her)... but except the fact that she vanished... no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give her Wreath of Immortalles which is obtained from Hermit from his quest.
This is bug in the game that no matter you helped her or not, there is no mention about it in the game. Its mentioned even in Witcher Wikia.